# Substituting the values of a Matrix into an array in R

Tags: r

I wanted to substitute the values of an Matrix into the array. Consider the following code.

```
n = 3
irfh = 12 
itrn = 100 
burnin = 15
irf1 = array(0, dim=c(n,irfh,itrn))
lj = matrix(1:36,3,12)
for(i in 1:(itrn+burnin)){
  
  if(i > burnin){
   
   irf1[,,i] = lj
  }
}
```

I tried to execute these codes but I am getting the error which is -

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , , i, value = lj) : subscript out of bounds
```

Can someone enlighten me what is going wrong in this.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: irf1 is an array, lj is a matrix, you cannot insert a matrix into an array (dimension).

Comment: @user2974951 Yes, it is possible. A 3d array can be seen as several matrices stacked together.

Comment: Just do `for(i in 1:itrn)`. Tested with a smaller array and smaller `burnin`. Even better, `for(i in seq_len(itrn))`

Comment: @RuiBarradas in which part you don't understand the role of burnin? In the for loop or in the if loop?

Comment: It was in the `for`, but in the mean time I have deleted that comment. All clear now.

Comment: @RuiBarradas this same thing is running perfectly in MATLAB but its giving errors in R.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion above? Different languages have different indexing and assignment rules. In R it is possible to access a vector beyond its last element, so I would have expected your code to extend the array.

Comment: It's possible to assign to an element beyond the last, as in `irf1[prod(dim(irf1)) + 1L]`, but the array looses the dim attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of irf1 should be "itrn + burnin" because in loop increase with index of vector. And add an comma in irf1 term, irf1[,,]. Then,

```
n = 3
irfh = 12 
itrn = 100 
burnin = 15
irf1 = array(0, dim=c(n,irfh,itrn + burnin)) 
lj = matrix(1:36,3,12)

for(i in 1:(itrn+burnin)){

  if(i > burnin){

    irf1[,,i] = lj
  } 
}
```